# sonar delphi plugin custom rule

Tags: delphi, sonarqube, sonar-runner

How to add custom rule in sonar for delphi  language? 
Our problem is we are able to add custom rule for all other languages like c#,javascript,java in sonar, but are not able to add for delphi, We can't find new rule option like the one showed in this [link for adding custom rules in sonar](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Extending+Coding+Rules) . Someone please advise.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the Delphi plugin, developed and maintained (?) by guys from [Sabre](http://www.sabre.com/), is not extensible: it does not have a rule extension mechanism, nor does it provide an XPath rule that could be used to achieve this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your information. but we should have to add our own custom rule for delphi language. Is there any other way to achieve our need apart from this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I agree. You should directly ask the question to the developers of the Delphi plugin on the Sonar user mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the (early) work we are doing to do [humane assessment](http://humane-assessment.com/) with Delphi, using [Moose](http://www.moosetechnology.org/).